# Find control by tag on WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dynamic `Label` with `Tag` which is created 14 `Label` and added in a `GroupBox`, then, I want to search for `Label` that have a `Tag = "ABC"`, I have tried this :

```
var items = grouptodayerror.ControlCollection;
var finditem = items.Cast<Control>().FirstOrDefault(control => String.Equals(control.Tag, "ABC");
```

`grouptodayerror` is my `GroupBox`, and getting an error message

```
Error   1   'ControlCollection': cannot reference a type through an expression; try 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' instead
```

I tried this too :

```
Label findbox = grouptodayerror.Controls.Find("ABC", true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
  if (findbox != null)
  findbox.Text = "CDE";
```

But I'm getting error `null reference` on first line.

My question is :

1. How can I get the `ControlCollection`?
2. Did the second code can find a `Tag` or just a `Text` of `Control`?
3. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the first section of code would be right, but Id imagine your items should be grouptodayerror.Controls.. not controlcolleciton

Comment: You should use [`Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx) property of yourcontrol: `yourControl.Controls`. Also instead of `Tag` you can set `Name` of control and find it by name. `yourControl.Controls.Find("childname", True).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Try `var lbl = grouptodayerror.Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.Tag?.ToString() == "ABC");`

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38648452/3110834) for example.

Comment: @BugFinder : Poor me, i have to read more about `Controls` and `ControlCollection`, thanks, its working now
@RezaAghaei : Yes, thanks its working now
@ZoharPeled : Thanks, i'll try it later on

Comment: @SomeRandomPeople You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one

```
foreach (Label lb in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().SelectMany(groupBox => groupBox.Controls.OfType<Label>()).ToList())
        {
            if (lb.Tag.Equals("ABC"))
            {
                //Write your logic here
            }
        }
```