# Access variable's value via its string name C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to store a series (six to be precise) of Windows Forms labels in an array. There are six labels, which follow the naming convention `orderLabel0`, `orderLabel1`... `orderLabel5`.

I would like to store the pointers to the orderLabels in an array:

```
Label[] orderLabels = new Label[6];
for(int index = 0; index < 6; index++)
{                
    orderLabels[index] = orderLabel + [index]; //Error!
}
```

The code somehow needs to treat the string as variable name and store them as "labels" rather than string in the orderLabels array. In other words, when `orderLabels[0]` is accessed, I am actually accessing `orderLabel0`.

Research here and there have led me to `dynamic`, `Reflection` and `Dictionary` options. However, they all require me to specify the object names (correct me if I am wrong), and I am trying to follow the "Do Not Repeat" yourself rule by not having to specify the object six times.

Please advise, thank you.

Comment: create a hashmap... i find it very funny that if i google most of these questions exactly ill get a stack overflow question with the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293549/string-to-variable-name

Comment: child controls are already stored in the parent container `Controls` property

Comment: Does `orderLabel0` to `orderLabel5` already exist on your form?

Comment: Hi Reza and Seany84, yes there are.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38648452/3110834). You can simply find them using their names. The name which you need to use in the loop is `string.Format("orderLabel{0}", index)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Controls` form variable to look up the control by name:

```
Label[] orderLabels = new Label[6];
for(int index = 0; index < 6; index++)
{                
    orderLabels[index] = Controls[string.Format("orderLabel{0}", index)] as Label;
}
```