# Get only the groupBoxes from a winform

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, groupbox

i made this code for get all the groupboxes from a winform and then take only the ones with a determinated name.

```
Control.ControlCollection controles = this.Controls;   
GroupBox gBoxAux = new GroupBox();             
List<GroupBox> gBoxes = new List<GroupBox>();

foreach (Control c in controles)
{                                        
   if (c.GetType() == typeof(GroupBox))
   {
       gBoxAux = (GroupBox)c;
       gBoxes.Add(gBoxAux);                        
   }
}
```

I don't know if there's a better way to do it instead of iterate over all the controls.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `var groupBox = this.Controls.Find("SomeName",true).FirstOrDefault()`. You may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38648452/3110834) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query that using Linq:

```
this.Controls.OfType<GroupbBox>().Where(x=> x.Name == "SomeName").ToList();
```

Comment: I assume that in: x=> x.Name = "SomeName" is '==', right? And something like this.Controls.OfType<GroupbBox>().Where(x=> x.Name == "SomeName" || x.Name == "AnotherName").ToList(); Would work?

Comment: @S.Medina Yes It works. You can also define a List of names then use `yourNamesList.Contains(x.Name)`

Answer (score 1):

Well to find all groupboxes there is no better way than to iterate over all of them. But (for me) the code would look better with this:

```
List<GroupBox> gBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<GroupbBox>().ToList();
```

`OfType<T>` selects all elements of a sequence that are of that type.

Note that this only finds all groupboxes directly contained in this `ControlCollection` but not in sub-containers. You may want to collect the groupboxes recursively:

```
public IEnumerable<GroupBoxes> GetAllGroupBoxes(Control c)
{
    return c.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>()
                     .Concat(c.Controls.OfType<Control>().SelectMany(GetAllGroupBoxes));
}

List<GroupBox> gBoxes = GetAllGroupBoxes(this).ToList();
```

To filter for a specific name you can use `Where`:

```
Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().Where(gb => gb.Name == "whatever")...
```

Comment: Wow, very very useful this LINQ method. Thanks!